# Defining a unique function for each object

Tags: c++

I have a class, along with it's objects. What do I do if I want each object to do something different? (AKA each object has a unique function).

Here is a simplified code of what I am trying to achieve.

**The basic class**

```
class Thing
{
private:
    int x, y, z;
public:
    static vector<Thing*> objects;

    int getX() {return x;}
    int getY() {return y;}
    int getZ() {return z;}

    Thing(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        this->x = X;
        this->y = Y;
        this->z = Z;

        objects.push_back(this);
    }

    void func(); //THE EVENTUAL UNIQUE FUNCTION
};
vector<Thing*> Thing::objects = {};
```

**My theoretical desired code**

```
int main()
{
    Thing A(1, 2, 3);

    void A->func() //A REDEFINITION OF THE PUBLIC FUNCTION
    {
        cout << "do stuff" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A basic ( but dirty ) answer would be add some function pointer into you constructor and put it into the member func ( should be function pointer too ),. But this is not OO. Instead make the class Thing  a Base Class and func() a pure virtual function. Derived classes will concretely implement the behavior of the "unique" function. Access object through base class pointer

Comment: If each object has a different function, then they are not from the same class. Class is a well defined object model in OOP. Learn inheritance and polymorphism to handle this.

Comment: Do you want to define/set the functions at run-time or at compile-time?

Comment: OOP is not the Holy Grail of Programming, C++ is not a purely OO language, and C++ is not the best OO language, And,after all, there isn't any formal model for OO Design, only practical and common sense backed guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::function and C++11 lambdas

```
class Thing
{
private:
    int x, y, z;
public:
    static vector<Thing*> objects;

    int getX() {return x;}
    int getY() {return y;}
    int getZ() {return z;}

    Thing(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        this->x = X;
        this->y = Y;
        this->z = Z;

        objects.push_back(this);
    }

    std::function<void()> func; //THE EVENTUAL UNIQUE FUNCTION
};
```

Redefine unique function

```
A.func = [&A]() {  
  // do something
};
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is exactly like the example given by OP, just translated to valid C++.

Comment: I suppose, this solution lacks OOP.